# Bower : install fork of Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower, git-fork

I have a git repo which is basically a fork of Bootstrap.

It has been modified and i can push on an other repo than the official one.
It is still possible to pull from Bootstrap (to get updates).

My problem here is, when i enter `bower install http://my_custom_url.git` bower download the official Bootstrap repo and not mine.

I can't figure out why and unfortunately i cannot share the real url of my repo (it's locked by my company).

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Have you comitted your changes

Comment: I do not have anything changed. Someone forked bootstrap in my company to custom styles, i want to clone this repo in my app with bower but i only get bower.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you specify otherwise Bower downloads the latest **release** from your repo.

If you haven't created a new release, it will appear that Bower is downloading from the original Github branch. The latest release on your forked repo is the same as that of the original.

One option is to create a new release for your forked repo and it should work as expected.

Or, you could use `bower install http://my_custom_url.git#commit` where `commit` is the name of the latest commit with your edits to the Bootstrap code.

You could use `branchname` instead of `commit` but then you risk having the code change without you realizing it.

Comment: i thought about it but as i said, the repo is not mine and make a fork of a fork just to change the release is kinda ... bad right ? Is this the only way to make this work ?

Comment: @Maxime updated my answer, you could also specify the commit that includes your modifications.

Comment: i didn't know it was possible to tell which commit i want ! This sounds awesome, i'll come back soon to tell you if it's ok because right now i can't do it :)

Comment: Amazing ! I spent 2 hours looking for this, thanks for your answer ! Exactly what i was looking for ! Just, do you know if bower update will update the commit hash to the latest release ?

Comment: @Maxime no if there are additional commits to bootstrap core you'd have to pull those into the forked repo (or make a pull request to bootstrap repo). If you want sways the latest commit from that forked repo just specify the branch (e.g., "master", to pull the latest master branch rather than a specific commit).